# Lookup table population via Visual Studio dbproj scripts -- best practices?

Tags: .net, sql, database-project

I'm using a Database Project to create all the tables needed for my .NET MVC application. What I am wondering is, is there a common "best practice" for populating my lookup tables? I'm new to .NET database projects, and I don't know where to put a script for this, or whether I should even use a script. (I'm thinking I should though.)

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio, and which edition?

Comment: VS2010 Premium, .NET 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Post-Deployment script to perform actions like this. You can still keep individual scripts for the actions necessary for each table, and "include" them into the Post-Deployment script.

This combined script will then be appended to the deployment script on every deployment.

```
:r .\Populate-Table1.sql
:r .\Populate-Table2.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any best practices per se, but I keep separate scripts for each table I need to populate with data. So I'll have a folder called, say, "InitialData", and a bunch of files underneath "Table1.sql", "Table2.sql", etc.

Comment: Looks like a nice simple way, thanks. Do those scripts get automatically added to the deploy (or is there an easy way to add them)?